# Parse contract to retrieve declared identifiers

Tags: solidity, solc, parser

[Node.js Solidity compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc) parses contract and returns its ABI, is there any library to retrieve all declared identifiers in a contract?

For example, the following contract:

```
contract Person {
    uint id;
    bytes firstName;
    bytes lastName;
}
```

Should be parsed to:

```
identifiers: [
  {
    type: "uint",
    name: "id"
  },
  {
    type: "bytes",
    name: "firstName"
  },
  {
    type: "bytes",
    name: "lastName"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ConsenSys/solidity-parser](https://github.com/consensys/solidity-parser) and walk the resulting AST looking for variable declarations. There are no visitors included in the package, so you will have to write one yourself.

Comment: And how? As it is currently written it's rather a comment than an answer.